# A fact about independent exponentially distributed RVs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let's say $Y_i$ are independent exponentially distributed with rates $c_i$ which can be assumed to be all in $(0, \infty)$ but not necessarily the same.  Whenever $t\geq0, K\geq0$ let $N_t^k=\inf\left\{n\geq 0:\sum_{i=k}^{k+n}Y_i>t\right\}$  Then it is supposed to be true, as I'm struggling to show, that $$\forall t\geq0, s\geq0, k, l\geq0,\quad P(N_t^0=k, N_{t+s}^0=k+l)=P(N_t^0=k)P(N_s^k=l).$$  This is essentially the stated exercise on p.75 in this errata: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tml/bookcorrections3.pdf

After I have filtered out some trivial cases.  One can assume WLOG also that $t, s>0$.  I have some work done on this where I condition on $Y_0, ... Y_k$ but not with any fruit worth showing as it's just a string of messy expressions.  I also have thought that maybe this is some sort of "memoryless property" and also that it is possible I may need to condition not on $Y_0, ... Y_k$ but rather on $N_t^0$.  But I would not know how to proceed in the last way either.